# java: how to use String value as the class Name and variable name

Tags: java, android

I have String variable like

```
String android1="TextInputLayout";
String android1var = "customTextInputLayoutemail"
String android2="TextInputEditText";
String android2var = "textInputEditTextemail"
```

I want to create the following code:

```
CustomTextInputLayout customTextInputLayoutemail = null;
TextInputEditText textInputEditTextemail = null;

customTextInputLayoutemail = new CustomTextInputLayout(this);
customTextInputLayoutemail.setLayoutParams(new CustomTextInputLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

textInputEditTextemail = new TextInputEditText(this);
textInputEditTextemail.setHint("");
customTextInputLayoutemail.addView(textInputEditTextemail);
customTextInputLayoutemail.setHelperText("min "+MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH+" characters");
```

How can i replace

```
class Name CustomTextInputLayout with android1
class Name TextInputEditText with android2

variable Name textInputEditTextemail with android1var
variable Name customTextInputLayoutemail with android2var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) to create View dynamically. To get `constructor` use [getConstructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29) and use [newInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Constructor#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) method to create instance.

**Sample code:**

```
    String android1="TextInputLayout";
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.support.design.widget." + android1);
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Context.class);
        Object object = constructor.newInstance(getContext());

        if (object instanceof TextInputLayout) {
            TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) object;
        }else {   
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class.forname() to get a class using the string name https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String).
Like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```